# BeautifulSoup exception handling of structure

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to implement an exception handling in my code. I'm scraping data from [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.de/pep-guardiola/erfolge/trainer/5672). If you look at the attached picture, you will see that in season 10/11 there's a missing entry. BS doesn't find any matchings there and just skips it. I've implemented some code that checks the full length at the end and just appends the list with a 'MISSING'. Unfortunately, I can just append this at the end of any page. Thus, if there is a missing entry in the middle of the table, I have to move it manually. The problem is that my year/season don't fit after such missing entries.

Can this be done with selenium?

Relevant part of my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/pep-guardiola/erfolge/trainer/5672'

headers = {'Host': 'www.transfermarkt.de',
           'Referer': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/manuel-neuer/erfolge/spieler/17259',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

pageTree = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'lxml')

for title in soup.select('.box td.hauptlink > a'):
    list5.append(str('xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de') + str(title['href']))
    for titlelink in title.find_all('img'):
        list4.append(str(titlelink['alt']))

missingentries = len(list3) - len(list4)
for x in range(0, missingentries):
    list4.append(str('MISSING'))

missinglinks = len(list4) - len(list5)
for x in range(0, missinglinks):
    list5.append(str('MISSING'))
```

[image]

My output:
[image: My output]

Output I want:
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide an  expected output?

Comment: I have updated the description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are isolating each of these related elements while parsing them. Once they have been stored into individual lists then you canot find the missing element index.

What you can do is to first get these elements together and then insert `'MISSING'` into the list at that point itself. In that case you can use exception to catch the missing element. I would have preferred to store these in a *list of list*  instead of a separate list for each element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/pep-guardiola/erfolge/trainer/5672'
headers = {'Host': 'www.transfermarkt.de',
           'Referer': 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/manuel-neuer/erfolge/spieler/17259',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
pageTree = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html5lib')
list3=[]
list4=[]
list5=[]
for td in soup.find_all('td',class_='hauptlink'):
    date=td.find_previous_sibling("td")
    list3.append(date.text)
    try:
        list4.append(str(td.a.find('img')['alt']))
        list5.append(str('xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de') + str(td.a['href']))
    except AttributeError:
        list5.append('MISSING')
        list4.append('MISSING')
#just for viewing output
for item in zip(list3,list4,list5):
    print(item)
```

Output

```
('10/11', 'LaLiga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/primera-division/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2010')
('08/09', 'LaLiga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/primera-division/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2008')
('10/11', 'UEFA Champions League', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/uefa-champions-league/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CL/saison_id/2010')
('08/09', 'UEFA Champions League', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/uefa-champions-league/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CL/saison_id/2008')
('17/18', 'Premier League', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1/saison_id/2017')
('10/11', 'LaLiga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/primera-division/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2010')
('09/10', 'LaLiga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/primera-division/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2009')
('08/09', 'LaLiga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/primera-division/startseite/wettbewerb/ES1/saison_id/2008')
('15/16', '1.Bundesliga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/saison_id/2015')
('14/15', '1.Bundesliga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/saison_id/2014')
('13/14', '1.Bundesliga', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/1-bundesliga/startseite/wettbewerb/L1/saison_id/2013')
('18/19', 'EFL Cup', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/league-cup/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CGB/saison_id/2018')
('17/18', 'EFL Cup', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/league-cup/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CGB/saison_id/2017')
('13/14', 'UEFA Super Cup', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/uefa-supercup/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/USC/saison_id/2013')
('11/12', 'UEFA Super Cup', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/uefa-supercup/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/USC/saison_id/2011')
('09/10', 'UEFA Super Cup', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/uefa-supercup/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/USC/saison_id/2009')
('13/14', 'FIFA Klub-WM', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/fifa-klub-wm/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/KLUB/saison_id/2013')
('11/12', 'FIFA Klub-WM', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/fifa-klub-wm/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/KLUB/saison_id/2011')
('09/10', 'FIFA Klub-WM', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/fifa-klub-wm/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/KLUB/saison_id/2009')
('10/11', 'MISSING', 'MISSING')
('15/16', 'DFB-Pokal', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/dfb-pokal/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/DFB/saison_id/2015')
('13/14', 'DFB-Pokal', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/dfb-pokal/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/DFB/saison_id/2013')
('11/12', 'Copa del Rey', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/copa-del-rey/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CDR/saison_id/2011')
('08/09', 'Copa del Rey', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/copa-del-rey/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/CDR/saison_id/2008')
('11/12', 'Supercopa', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/supercopa/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/SUC/saison_id/2011')
('10/11', 'Supercopa', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/supercopa/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/SUC/saison_id/2010')
('09/10', 'Supercopa', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/supercopa/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/SUC/saison_id/2009')
('18/19', 'Community Shield', 'xhttps://www.transfermarkt.de/community-shield/startseite/pokalwettbewerb/GBCS/saison_id/2018')
```